# Getting data from the JSON

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get the data from the below JSON output. I am unable to get the data using the below mentioned java code. Could you please help me to correct my code ?

```
[
  {
"id": "bitcoin",
"symbol": "btc",
"name": "Bitcoin", 
  }
]
```

**Code**

```
public void loadAltCoins(String result) {

    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(reader);

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println("Testing ID : " + json_data.getString("id"));
        }
}
```

Comment: you're getting array and parsing it in object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a JSONObject(`{}`) for JSONArray (`[]`) so use

```
//JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(result); not required
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     System.out.println("Testing ID : " + json_data.optString("id"));
}// use optString, no exception and auto parsing
```